# Procedure to find period of sum of product of discrete sinusoids?

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions, discrete-time

**Context :**

[image]

i'm unable to understand the underlined portion

and when i was solving this question for finding it's period i'm not getting final answer

**question:**

[image]

the fundamental period of first product term is $\dfrac{16\times 15}{gcd(16,15)}=240$ and fundamental period of  second product term is $\dfrac{8\times 6}{gcd(8,6)}=24$.so,**fundamental period** of sum of these product terms i.e, $x[n]$ will be $\dfrac{240\times 24}{gcd(240,24)}=240$ but answer given is **120** and it is however smaller as written in the textbook . but **how do i know when it will be smaller**

**note:**

all functions are discrete sequences means $n$ can take only integer values

Comment: Even the first statement about the **sum** function having *fundamental period* as the expression in (1.2) is incorrect. Think what if $x_2(n)=-x_1(n)$, then the sum function is $0$ and the fundamental period is arbitrarily small.

Comment: @AnuragA it should hold if the sequence resulting from adding is non-constant.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg But the result as stated is about **any** periodic sequences $x_1(n)$ and $x_2(n)$, hence incorrect.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Nope. Take periods (1,2,3,4) and (5,2,3,0) for instance, both of period 4. The sum has period (6,4,6,4). The fundamental period is 2.

Comment: cosine and sine are made from complex exponential signals(who are periodic) so please answer in that context only . i'm just asking how do i know the period calculated by (1.2) is the fundamental one . not it's integral multiple . even author said it may be smaller

Comment: @FaradayPathak It's not difficult to represent a periodic sequence of integers as a sum of trig functions. Use the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: @Jean Claude Arbaut : yes true , but do you know any general method to how to find periods of sums of discrete trig. functions i agree with you and you proved (1.2)  is incorrect so what is correct formula .

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Your claim about constant sequence is also incorrect as illustrated by Jean-Claude in the example. In general, if you take $x_2(n)=-x_1(n)+f(n)$, where the fundamental period of $f(n)$ is a *proper* divisor of the fundamental period of $x_1(n)$, then the **sum** sequence will have fundamental period as that of $f(n)$ and will not be equal to the answer given by the expression (1.2).

Comment: If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two periods, then $gcd(N_1,N_2)$ is a period (use Bézout's theorem). Hence the fundamental period is a divisor of $N_1$ and $N_2$. Not much more can be said without more information.

Comment: okay got it now(to some extent) . thanks to all of you ,Jean - Claude Arbaut ,Anurag A and dinosaurEgg. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental period is the smallest $k>0$ such that $u(n+k)=u(n)$.

Actually the first result stated is wrong: even for a sum you have no such guarantee on the fundamental period.

Take for instance:

$$u(n)=0,1,0,1,\dots$$
$$v(n)=1,0,1,0,\dots$$

They have period $N_1=N_2=2$. The fundamental period of the sum should be

$$N=\frac{N_1N_2}{gcd(N_1,N_2)}=2$$

But $u(n)+v(n)=1,1,1,1,\dots$

Here the fundamental period of the sum is $1$.

Note that the fundamental period of $u(n)v(n)$ is also $1$, since $u(n)v(n)=0,0,0,0,\dots$.

---

Regarding the preent specific case,

$$u(n)=\cos(\frac{n\pi}{8})\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{15})+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4})$$

The trig functions have period resp. 16,15,6,8, hence the lcm of these numbers is certainly a period of $u$, that is $240$.

Is it the smallest?

The prime divisors of $240$ are $2$, $3$ and $5$. The simplest may be to check $u(240/2)$, $u(240/3)$ and $u(240/5)$ and compare to $u(0)=1$.

We have

$$u(120)=\cos(15\pi)\cos(16\pi)+\sin(40\pi)\sin(3\pi)=-1$$
$$u(80)=\cos(10\pi)\cos(10\pi+2\pi/3)+\sin(26\pi+2\pi/3)\sin(20\pi)=-1/2$$
$$u(48)=\cos(6\pi)\cos(6\pi+2\pi/5)+\sin(16\pi)\sin(12\pi)=\cos(2\pi/5)\ne1$$

Conclusion: no divisor of $240$ may be a smaller period. Hence $240$ is the fundamental period.

Comment: but he have also written it may be smaller (the underlined portion)

Comment: @FaradayPathak Hence you understand that underlined statement.

Comment: @FaradayPathak I added a possible solution. It's often a good idea to have a look at specific values of the function, and how they repeat. Another possibility,I guess, would be to linearize the trig function (that is, rewrite the function without products of trigs, using trig identities). Then consider the period of each term, or groups of terms with same period.